# How to transform a fraction with square root in denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Simple question but my math is a bit rusty.

> How does $\frac{20}{\sqrt5} = 4\sqrt5$?

I tried multiplying by $\frac{\sqrt5}{\sqrt5}$ but that's not right.

Comment: And how exactly is it "not right"?

Comment: Actually multiplying by $\frac{sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}}$ is correct: $\frac{20}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot\frac{sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}}=\frac{20\sqrt{5}}{5}=4\sqrt{5}$

Comment: is it?? 20/sqrt(5) * sqrt(5)/sqrt(5) = sqrt(5)*sqrt(5) = 20sqrt(5). I'm not sure where to go next.

Comment: Yes, the numerator becomes $20 \sqrt 5$. And The denominator becomes $\sqrt 5\times \sqrt 5 = (\sqrt 5)^2 = 5$.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, multiplying the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt 5$ is spot on. Perhaps you made an arithmetic error? Let's try it again:

$$\frac{20}{\sqrt 5} \times  \frac {\sqrt 5}{\sqrt 5} = \frac {20\sqrt 5}{5} = 4\sqrt 5$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{20}{\sqrt{5}} &= \frac{20}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}} = \frac{20\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}.\sqrt{5}} \\
&= \frac{20\sqrt{5}}{5} = 4\sqrt{5}
\end{align}$$